# How can I create a Gantt Chart

Tags: centos, productivity

How can I create a Gantt chart if I'm running CentOS 8?

This is for standard project planning application -- I want to lay out the schedule for a bunch of work. I'm aware of TaskJuggler but want to be able to schedule the start/stop times of the tasks myself.

Comment: Are you asking for a software recommendation such as ProjectLibre?

Comment: Sure, if it’ll let me make a Gantt chart

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/